# Ajax Calls to database table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a database table called "mytable" with 1 column called col1. 
This column takes values 0 and 1 and it's updated every 15 minutes. 
I want a working example with a PHP page that will make an ajax call to this table and show image1 if value is 0 and image2 if value is 1.

This ajax called must be fired automatically every minute. Is it posisble?

thanks for the help

Comment: To do this automatically without any intervention from you or anyone else, requires CRON. Otherwise, you or anyone else would require their web browser to be constantly open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. More research would show you how but here is how you can do it;

First build a function that does an ajax call;

```
function call()
{
    return data; // Ajax here
}
```

then call it with an interval;

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  call();
}, 5000);
```

This will call it every 5 seconds. For the PHP part, you will need to do more research. You can simply create a page called Data.php and post to that page with jquery post or ajax then simply retrieve the data and parse it.